# A question in Abstract Algebra about cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to solve this problem but without success:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Build an injective function from $G/H$ (the set of left cosets of $H$) to $H\setminus G$ (the set of right cosets of $H$). Note that $|G/H|=|H\setminus G|$.

I would like to get help with this question.
Thanks.

Comment: The left or right cosets of a subgroup are not themselves always groups, so I changed your post to speak of a set of cosets, not a group of cosets. Also, learn how to spell the word coset.

Comment: That's kinda rude... not everyones first language is english.

Comment: @Jim Just out of curiosity, in what language is coset spelled cosset?

Comment: In other languages, it's called some word in that language. If it was translated to English, and the result was off by a single letter and still identifiable, then that's pretty damn good. I'm with Jim.

Comment: Maybe stop complaining about my English and start helping me with a solution :D.

Comment: My wish for the new year is that we interpret short comments on the Internet as charitably as possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that the inverse function $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ sends left cosets to right cosets and vice versa.